# How will handScroll work when it is getting removed by cleanup function

Tags: reactjs, react-component-unmount

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const Navbar = () => {
  const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleScroll = () => {
      if (window.scrollY >= 50) {
        setIsVisible(true);
      } else {
        setIsVisible(false);
      }
    };

    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <nav
      className={`fixed top-0 left-0 right-0 z-50 py-4 transition-opacity duration-300 backdrop-blur-sm backdrop-brightness-120 ${
        isVisible ? "opacity-100" : "opacity-0 hidden"
      }`}
    >
      <div className="container mx-auto flex justify-end">
        <div className="flex items-center space-x-4">
          <a href="#" className="text-primary hover:text-gray-900">
            Home
          </a>
          <a href="#" className="text-primary hover:text-gray-900">
            About
          </a>
          <a href="#" className="text-primary hover:text-gray-900">
            Projects
          </a>
          <a href="#" className="text-primary hover:text-gray-900">
            Contact
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  );
};

export default Navbar;
```

I would like to know how is the handle Scroll function still working even after the component is unmounted?

I am not sure if I understood the process, can someone shed some light on this?
I do understand the lifecycle of react component but inside useEffect is where I am confused, specially return in useEffect`

Comment: `handleScroll `  in line `window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);` is a different `handleScroll` than in line `window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);`. `handleScroll` is created multiple times. You should place this function inside `useEffect`

Comment: Will do, could you also tell me how it will work once it gets unmounted. Because when I check the console, I could see that it gets unmounted immediately. So I was wondering how is it still listening to the scroll event?

Comment: `window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);` doesn't do anything because `handleScroll` is a different listener than you added

Comment: @Konrad I have made the changes as advised, now could you shed some light on the above doubt?
In simple terms all I want to know is that, why is the scroll event still working when the event listener has been removed by the cleaner function. 
PS: kindly guide me accordingly, thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that the component is not rendered?

Comment: @Konrad it works completely fine, the Navbar acts exactly as I wanted it to. But I am confused about the process that is going behind it.

Comment: If it's rendered than it's not unmounted. I guess that you have a strict mode turned on and component is initially unmounted and mounted again

Comment: @Konrad that was it. I was so confused why it is acting that way. Thanks a lot, for explaining. Now it all make sense.